# Pick all documents and send to server

Tags: file, pdf, audio, directory, document

How I fetch all the documents from different different directories and after how I send to server by using swift language

Please answer me of my question because I am new here and I got this task but I don't know how to do it so please help me

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to recursively search for documents in all directories, you can use a recursive function to traverse the directory structure and fetch all documents. Here's an example:

```swift
import Foundation

func sendAllDocumentsToServer() {
    let documentsDirectoryURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    
    fetchAndSendDocumentsRecursively(from: documentsDirectoryURL)
}

func fetchAndSendDocumentsRecursively(from directoryURL: URL) {
    do {
        let contents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: directoryURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [])

        for itemURL in contents {
            var isDirectory: ObjCBool = false
            if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: itemURL.path, isDirectory: &isDirectory) {
                if isDirectory.boolValue {
                    // Recursive call for subdirectories
                    fetchAndSendDocumentsRecursively(from: itemURL)
                } else {
                    // Fetch and send the document
                    sendDocumentToServer(documentURL: itemURL)
                }
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}

func sendDocumentToServer(documentURL: URL) {
    let serverURL = URL(string: "your_server_upload_endpoint")!

    var request = URLRequest(url: serverURL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let task = URLSession.shared.uploadTask(with: request, fromFile: documentURL) { data, response, error in
        // Handle server response
        if let error = error {
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        } else if let data = data {
            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            print("Server Response: \(responseString ?? "")")
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}

// Call the function to send all documents
sendAllDocumentsToServer()
```

In this example:

- The `sendAllDocumentsToServer` function starts the process by fetching documents from the app's document directory.
- The `fetchAndSendDocumentsRecursively` function is a recursive function that traverses through all subdirectories and fetches documents.
- The `sendDocumentToServer` function is responsible for sending each document to the server.

Adjust the code according to your specific requirements, and make sure to replace `"your_server_upload_endpoint"` with your actual server endpoint.